# NPM run a single test suite from a directory of test suites

Tags: npm

I have a directory full of test suites located at ./test/sec/

to run all of those I use:

```
npm run test:sec
```

What I would like to do is just run one of the test suites in that directory, example ./test/sec/mySuite.ts

Things I have tried:

```
npm run test:sec test/sec/mySuite.ts
npm run test:sec/mySuite.ts
npm test test/sec/mySuite.ts -t "GET /spawn"
```

And many variations of that kind of guesswork.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please ahre your package.json and which testing library you use. Otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: @pigrammer I believe my test library is jest, I am not sure what you mean by ahre my package.json but it is here:  https://github.com/NeuraLegion/sectester-js-demo/blob/master/package.json

Thanks

Comment: oops, that's a typo, it should be share